# Unity: Model Construction on the fly

Tags: unity, models, 3d-meshes, voxels

*So, forgive me if some of the terminology is wrong, I am just getting started with Unity again and I can't remember the proper names. I'm also on my phone, so I didn't have unity in front of me when I posted this question.*

I am beginning work on a voxel based game. Everything in the game will be models constructed of 64 by 64 cubes. I would like to, with the code given, say, a 4096 bit array, be able to construct a model in the game with those cubes. I know that you can programmatically add models that you have imported into unity, but I want to make contiguous meshes programmatically, with highest performance being the goal. I do not want a certain amount of little 1x1 cube meshes positioned right next to each other, but specifically one model.

**Is this possible?**

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You can use the Mesh class to dynamically create whatever shapes you want. The efficient construction of a mesh from a list of voxels is not trivial though, so a complete solution is likely to be too long for an answer. My advice would be to make a start yourself, and if you run into trouble, ask a question specific to the snag you've hit.

Comment: "Is this possible?" is just a yes or no question; you should ask "how?"

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest checking out [AlexStv's Voxel Tutorial](http://alexstv.com/index.php/posts/unity-voxel-block-tutorial).  It's written for C# in Unity3d, has been iterated upon several times, and covers everything from generating the meshes and texture up through setting up collisions and integrating a first-person camera.